# Using MIN() inside ARRAYFORMULA()

Tags: google-sheets, min, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I've seen some examples of using `SUM()` inside an `ARRAYFORMULA()` in Google Spreadsheets (and oddly enough, they all seem like workarounds) but I can't figure out how to apply them to using `MIN()` instead.

Let's say I have columns `A`, `B` and `C` and I just want to get the result of `MIN(A:C)` on the `D` column, just for the three cells that would match each row. The straightforward way should be `ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(A1:C))` but surely enough that doesn't work.

How can I programmatically calculate the `MIN()` of some cells within a row, for all the rows in a Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 16):

`MIN()` always returns a single value, regardless of the range size, so `ARRAYFORMULA()` does not change the output - it only helps convert formulas that do not handle a range.

As a quick answer, you could simply rewrite the logic of `MIN()` using something like `IF()`:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A:A < B:B, if (A:A < C:C, A:A, C:C), if(B:B < C:C, B:B, C:C)))`

Comment: This works fine for few columns but becomes *really* nasty as the column number increases. I read the original question as looking for a general solution with "Let's say I have columns `A`, `B` and `C`" as just there to just explain the problem. The solution for four columns in case anyone needs to use it is `=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A:A < B:B,if(A:A < C:C,if(A:A < D:D, A:A, D:D),if(C:C < D:D, C:C, D:D)),if(B:B < C:C,if(B:B < D:D, B:B, D:D),if(C:C < D:D, C:C, D:D))))`. The overall size about doubles for each extra column. 5 columns is just about manageable but takes 312 characters.

Comment: What is the solution for 5 colums?

Answer (score 4):

in D1 try this workaround/formula:

```
=index(ArrayFormula(transpose(query(transpose(A:C),"select "&join("),","min(Col"&row(indirect("A1:A"&count(A:A))))&")"))),,2)
```

and see if that works ?

Basically this

- first transposes numbers in A:C
- calculates the minimum for each column (QUERY function)
- then those minimum values are transposed back into rows

Comment: This appears to ignore the last row so I added +1 after `count(A:A)`

Answer (score 3):

Some "statistical" and "math" type functions - [AVERAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093615), [COUNT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093620), [MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013), [MIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094017), [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669) - each have a corresponding `*IF` and / or `*IFS` variant that, when combined with the [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) function, seem to satisfy this sort of need.

For example, I have a sheet named `monthly` with dates in column A and dollar amounts in column B. I wanted to get the minimum dollar amounts for rows where the date was in the year 2021.

Combining [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) and [MINIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256529) worked for me ...

```
=INDEX(MINIFS(monthly!$B$2:$B, YEAR(monthly!$A$2:$A), 2021))
```

Functions of this type include ...

- [AVERAGEIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256529), [AVERAGEIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256534)
- [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480), [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550)
- [MAXIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013817) (singular form doesn't seem to exist)
- [MINIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014063) (singular form doesn't seem to exist)
- [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583), [SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496)

Singular forms (`*IF`) match rows based on a single criterion. Plural forms (`*IFS`) match rows based on multiple criteria.

Answer (score 1):

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:C), 
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN( , ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A&B1:B&C1:C), 
 "min(Col"&ROW(A1:A)-ROW(A1)+1&"),", ""))), ".\z", "")&"")),
 "select Col2")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Is the `&""` necessary after the `REGEXREPLACE` call?

Comment: @AnnanFay yes. for safety reasons only tho. it depends on your dataset. regex formulas cant work with numeric values so by adding this chunk to it it will convert numeric values into text-string values.

Answer (score 1):

Updated solution from JPV to: avoid dropping the last row, allow for smaller ranges, and to be shorter.

**Data in A:C and Formula in D1:**

```
=TRANSPOSE(index(query(TRANSPOSE(A:C),"select "&textjoin(", ",1,arrayformula("min(Col"&ROW(A:C)&")"))),2))
```

**Data in A2:C14 and Formula in D2:**

```
=TRANSPOSE(index(query(TRANSPOSE(A2:C14),"select "&textjoin(", ",1,arrayformula("min(Col"&ROW(A2:C14)-Row()+1&")"))),2))
```

Explanation

- Convert rows into columns with `transpose`
- Query data with `select min(Col1)` for each column

  - Use `textjoin` to generate `min` queries (e.g. `min(Col1), min(Col2), ...`)
- Use `index` to remove query headings
- Use `Transpose` again to convert results from columns to rows