# Result of formula changing when encapsulating it in ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to calculate the elapsed time between a specific date and time and another date and time, excluding weekends and non-office hours.
I have done everything already and all seems to work correctly but for one formula.
[Here you can see the formula that gives me problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnmOJ.jpg), [while here you can see the same formula without the ArrayFormula encapsulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16p1q.jpg).
The result should be 08:00:00 like in screenshot 2, i can't understand what's going on with the first screenshot.

I need to have the formulas applied when the value are written in the columns from D to G, not before, that's the reason why i am using ArrayFormula. If there is another way to achieve the same result in another way let me know.

Thanks.

Edit: i have found that the issue is that the formula in column K is referencing a fixed cell in column E in the last bracket, `E2:E` is always a fixed cell in column E ([see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Keau.jpg)).
[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I6LokK2S1aEYmLJaCJ0_YnJWaHG4nqDw87NLjNV7Kgs/edit?usp=sharing) you can download a copy, thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help if you could share your spreadsheet file for replication purposes.

Comment: this is unsolvable unless you share a copy of your sheet or at least what is in B column on sheet `Constants`

Comment: Although this may not be the most sophisticated solution/workaround, you can try the answer from this quite identical post at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29887754 (by rewriting the logic of MIN()). Your formula on Column K could be something like: =ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(D2:D),,if(H2:H=0,0,ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Constants!$B$3 < Constants!$B$2-E2:E, TO_TEXT(Constants!$B$3), TO_TEXT(Constants!$B$2-E2:E)))))), 1027, 2)

Answer (score 0):

`MIN` is not supported by `ARRAYFORMULA`

You should instead use `if` to do the comparison

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isblank(D2:D),,if(H2:H=0,0,if(Constants!$B$3<Constants!$B$2-E2:E,Constants!$B$3,Constants!$B$2-E2:E))))
```